# php to my SQL insert

Tags: php, mysql

i have a small problem which i cannot find a way to overcome..
i am making a website for car's dealer, i made an insert page which inserts the cars details, i want the car's picture to be saved in a different directory for each car with the name of the folder's name being the car's ID.. i had no problem setting it up this way.

the problem is:

If i take the last ID in the database on the insert page first load then add one to it and put it in the insert statement there is no guarantee that when i upload the data the ID will be free anymore.. even if the last ID is taken at the update time as after the query comes back there could have been an insertion before the DB receives the data for insertion... the problem here is it will not be possible to insert the record anymore... the question here is: is it possible to reserve and ID somehow?

If i made it insert the record first then go to another page for image insertion then how will i be able to track it down, i wont have a way to correspond the uploaded images to the ID since there might be an insertion after my insertion and the last ID will no longer be for the car i have uploaded, so if i get the last ID and upload the images then the images will be uploaded to the wrong directory... the question here is: how can i track it?

or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: what i was looking for was mysql_insert_id() i wanted the generated ID from the query, i was incredibly new to PHP so forgive me if i was vague.. i did not know how to ask since i did not know what is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL AutoIncrement feature in the DB table, for ID column

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

And then use mysqli last insert ID, to get the last ID from DB

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

When you have that last (latest) ID, you can reuse it in your PHP in all places you need

Comment: that's known... but if i take the last ID and someone else inserts a record before i do.. then the ID i got will be invalid since it will be already used... lets say i get the last ID and it is 100 and i add one to make it 101, someone inserts before i do so last ID will be 101, i try to insert and upload with the ID 101 and it fails... unless i insert first therefore getting the ID first.. but when i try to get the last ID so i can upload the images using that ID but the same problem i mentioned ubove happens...

Comment: why are you adding numbers to ID? it is autogenerated (incrementaly) in the DB, so you don't need to add anything yourself. Let the database handle it. The only problem could be if at the exact same time (like in 0.0001 sec difference) two users will try to insert data, then id could be messed up, in that case use database transactions. But I think in your case it isn't necessary

Comment: then how can i get the ID so i can make a directory with the ID as name? i need to track the record so it doesn't mess up? is it possible to insert the record and get it's ID at the same time?? otherwise i cannot guarantee that when i check the last ID it will be the ID of the record i inserted.. since there will be a delay in getting the ID after inserting then calling... the only  way to make sure that i can think of is to present the user with the last 5 records to and let him choose the right one to upload the images to. i cannot upload the images unless i have the ID first

Comment: my answer says 'how'

Comment: i didn't check the second link.. but that is exactly what i need! thanks a lot!